# how to disable a textbox and also fetch the values and save in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to fetch values from textbox and save it to database. But the `textbox` should not be editable.

My problem is if the textbox is `disabled` then values in `textbox` should not be saved to database.
 **How to make a `textbox uneditable` and also save the value in database??**

Comment: try this:  <input type="text" name="abc" value="abc" readonly="readonly"/> to make the textbox uneditable

Comment: If you don't want the data in the database to change, then don't update the column.  You can't rely on the browser to enforce this constraint: it would be trivial for someone to submit altered data irrespective of the HTML involved.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer below that best matches your solution / or upvote downvote as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Why not make the `<textarea>` `readonly`?
It will be not editable but also not disabled.

Be aware that someone can still edit the text if they really wanted to, so you might have to account for user changes *(something easy like using Chrome Inspector to change the HTML in the form and submit the change to you)*